# How can i make swipe in mobile web page using selendroid webdriver?

Tags: java, selendroid

1. I have tried with below codings for swiping a mobile pages.
2. While running the test case, the swipe action doesn't occurs and i am also not getting any error message.
3. How can I swipe on both side from left to right and vice-versa.

   ```
   1. //Swipe Right to Left side of the Media Viewer First Page
                   WebElement firstPages = driver.findElement(By.id("media-list"));
                   TouchActions flick = new TouchActions(driver).flick(firstPages,-100,0,0);
                   flick.perform();

   2. //perform swipe gesture
                  TouchActions swipe = new TouchActions(driver).flick(0, -20);
                  swipe.perform();
   ```

   3.public static void swipe(WebDriver driver) {

   ```
               JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
               HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new java.util.HashMap<String, Double>();
               swipeObject.put("startX", 0.95);
               swipeObject.put("startY", 0.5);
               swipeObject.put("endX", 0.05);
               swipeObject.put("endY", 0.5);
               swipeObject.put("duration", 1.8);
               js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", swipeObject);
           }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Obtain the start point end point of the object to be swiped by using appium inspector or use settings->developer options->show pointer location to get starting and end point of object to be scrolled and then perform swipe on that co-ordinates with minimum duration of >500 , swipe wont work if u give any value below 500 in duration.        



        self.driver.swipe(start_x=300, start_y=281, end_x=75, end_y=281, duration=500)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.swipe(start_x=75, start_y=281, end_x=300, end_y=281, duration=500)
```